# What is the problem of this thermodynamic fallacy?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine

Consider the following (alleged) cycle:

1. **Quasi-static** adiabatic expansion of a vapor in such a condition that it results in the *condensation* of part of the mols*;
2. **Out of equilibrium** adiabatic compression;
3. **Quasi-static** isochoric heating;

Statements:

1. The latent heat required to change the state of part of the mols during steps 1 and 2 is due to the work done by the vapor;
2. Each infinitesimal compression *dV* during step 2 being done farther away from equilibrium than an infinitesimal expansion of same size done in step 1 at the same volume, grants that *if the internal energy in both cases were also the same* (*ie* all other factors being equal), a smaller molar fraction would be recovered to vaporous state than it was lost, so that
3. (lesser mols - lower energy feedback) with lesser mols recovered at each point of step 2, there is lower energy than in step 1, which implies a lower pressure, which implies a lower infinitesimal work done by each infinitesimal compression, which implies lower gain of latent heat, which yields an even lower recovery of vapor mols;
4. Steps 1 and 2 being done adiabatically, all the difference of work came from the internal energy of the mols. The initial state of step 1 and final state of step 2 have the same volume and different energies, and thus, step 3 can go from the latter to the former simply by means of a quasi-static heating.
5. We have, thus, performed a *closed loop in the space of thermodynamic states, whose only effect is the **total transformation of heat into work***, in other words, a ***heat engine with efficiency 1***.

The experiment can be more easily conceived by a piston that connects with a separated chamber that has the exact volume of condensed (or sublimed) mol fraction in the liquid (or solid) state. During step 1, the referred mol fraction 'rains' (or 'snows') into that chamber that is then closed so to completely prevent it to be recovered to the vapor fraction during step 2, *regardless even of how near the equilibrium it is done*. After step 2, the chamber is reopened, thus allowing those mols to be recovered to the vapor state in step 3.

The few experts on thermodynamics whom I have consulted haven't achieved to solve this apparent fallacy, which, I actually came up with before actually having formally studied thermodynamics, in my school days, back in 2008.

*The change of physical state to one of lower energy due to *[adiabatic cooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_process#Adiabatic_heating_and_cooling)* does happen, for example, in the formation of some types of clouds and in the sublimation of gaseous CO2 into dry ice in fire extinguishers.

Comment: I guess that step 2 is forbidden. It must be related to entropy, the out-equilibrium scenario must produce more entropy than the quasi-static one, so it cannot follow the path you are describing.

Comment: What forbids one to adiabatically compress the system resulting from step 1 out of equilibrium, back into the original volume? Moreover, in the first paragraph after the statements enumerations I provide a way to bypass the need for considerations on non-equilibrium thermodynamics.

Comment: It does not forbid to go back to the original volume. It forbids to go back adiabatically to the original volume and at a lower pressure. It basically says that going back adiabatically, you end up at a greater (or equal) pressure.

Comment: But why, since the mols that were condensed would be prevented, either by non static process or by physical removal, to from joining the vapor fraction again?

Comment: It is difficult for me to understand your phrasing in points 2 and 3. But one way or another, "a smaller molar fraction would be recovered to vaporous state than it was lost" is not possible. If you are out of equilibrium, you produce more entropy. Or your system may not be isolated from the outside world ?

Comment: ...Higher pressure with lesser mols, would require higher temperature, and thus more sensible heat, right? Where did it come from since there were lesser mols to work upon (which is the idea conveyed in statement 3)?

I claim that lesser mols would be recovered because the system is to be precisely in this condition of some types of clouds and fire extinguisher CO2, in which expansion causes condensation and compression causes vaporization. If the process (now, the compression), contrary to the expansion, is not quasi-static, lesser mols vaporize.

Comment: But, as I proposed, any consideration about non-equilibrium thermodynamics can be avoided if you suppose that the liquid mols are concealed to a fixed volumed chamber that remains closed during step 2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59126/discussion-between-yuri-s-vb-and-tony).